# How to change the color of a RadioGroup in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-radiogroup

I have added a RadioGroup to my app that only appears in certain situations.

Therefore I have not implemented any radio buttons in my XML file but only a RadioGroup which is either called up via Java ... or not. I am now trying to change the color of the radio buttons that appear.
Both the variant via Syles and the attribute `app: buttonTint = "@ color / primary"` did not generate any changes.

Is there a special attribute for RadioGroups to change the color of all subordinate RadioButtons or is it more sensible to program this directly via Java?

Due to the fact that my RadioGroup can contain different amounts of radio buttons, I would probably prefer the solution over Java.

Thanks for any Help!

**XML where the RadioGroup is located**

```
<RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/rdi_group_size"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="3"
                        android:buttonTint="@color/colorlightBlue"
                        />
```

The `app: buttonTint = "@ color / primary"` command is not working in this context.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why do u want to set the color of radiogrp any specific reason? u want to show the checked and unchecked situation?

Comment: When the RadioButtons come up one is always checked.... I want to change the color in wich this appears. But no I dont want to have to kind of statuses...

Answer (score 0):

In your values/colors file, you have a color: “coloraccent”, this is the default color of many buttons, radio, text etc.

Change the color accent to your favorite color, and you’re done :).

Comment: My Accent color : <color name="colorAccent">#FF29ABE2</color>, this is al light blue but when running the App the typical dark green from android gets shown. Changing anything there is not going to solve anything. The color in wich the buttons appear is in genral not in my colors.xml